# CNN model perfromance vaires with subset of validation dataset

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, residual-networks

I am training a resnet50 CNN model using fastai.The data is imbalanced, so I am doing undersampling.
first approach I tried to undersample only the training set, and the validation set is still imbalanced and my model ignores minority class totally, 0 F1 score.
Second approach, I tried to undersample both set and now my model is showing some F1 score for both classes.

I peformed 5 fold CV and its all same result.

Now, the validation set in second apporach is subset of first set. Also, validation set doesnt contribute in model learning, so I am not sure why the model behaves differently, though they are trained on same trainign set. Any idea?

Sample code

```
        train1, test1 = createTrainValDf(df)
        
        ## Oversample the training set
        train2 = undersample(train1, mal)
        #test2 = undersample(test1, mal)
        #train = sample(train, mal,int(400 * 0.8))
        ## expand it
        train_expanded = expandDf(train2, False)
        test_expanded = expandDf(test1, True)

        ## create data loader
        dataset_train = zfDataset(root, train_expanded)
        dataset_test = zfDataset(root, test_expanded)
        len(dataset_train), len(dataset_test)
        train_loader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=8, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True, shuffle=True)
        val_loader = DataLoader(dataset_test, batch_size=8, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True, shuffle= True)
        data_loaders = DataLoaders(train_loader, val_loader)
        
        ## start training
        learn = Learner(data_loaders, MVCNN(2), loss_func=CrossEntropyLossFlat(), metrics=[error_rate, accuracy])
        torch.cuda.set_device(0)
        
        learn.model.cuda()
        learn.unfreeze()
        learn.fit_one_cycle(10,lr_max=slice(1e-6, 1e-4),cbs=[EarlyStoppingCallback(monitor='accuracy', min_delta=0.01, patience=4),SaveModelCallback(monitor='accuracy', min_delta=0.001, fname=mal +"_a")])
        


def undersample(df, mal):
    c1,  c2 = df['Class'].value_counts()
    if c1 < c2:
        val= c1
    else:
        val = c2
    print(df['Class'].value_counts())
    class1  = df[df["Class"]==df['Class'].value_counts().index[0]]
    class2  = df[df["Class"]==df['Class'].value_counts().index[1]]
    df_1 = class1.sample(val, replace = False, random_state=45)
    df_2 = class2.sample(val, replace = False, random_state=45)
    df_m = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
    print("After undersample: " + str(len(df_1)) + " " + str(len(df_2)))
    return df_m
```